# Locating a control inside ListView template field

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, drop-down-menu, selectedindexchanged

I realize that this question may have been asked before... But I have a specific problem with this...

**my code**

```
foreach(ListViewItem item in listProducts.Items)
{
DropDownList dropList = listProducts.Items.FindControl("DropDownList1");
int SelectedID = Convert.ToInt32(listProducts.SelectedValue);
}
// now do something with that id...
```

The problem is that I lose the ID of the selected item from dropdown list once the foreach loop goes through the listview items...

I'm using this code in selectedindexchanged dropdown event to locate the desired ID and so that I may display the data to the user accordingly to what he selected from dropdown list...

So the idea is that when the user selects something from the drop down, i need to pick up the ID of the selected item and automatically display the product price when he selects it.

Can someone help me to solve this?

The listview:

```
 <asp:ListView ID="listProducts" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ProductID" OnItemDataBound="listProducts_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="listProducts_ItemCommand" OnSelectedIndexChanging="listProducts_SelectedIndexChanging">
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <div class="productoverlay">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 proizvod">
                             <div class="product">
                                 <div class="glow"></div>
                                 <img src='<%# "../productimg/" + Eval("FileName")%>'  alt='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>'/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         <div class="col-lg-1 price">
                             <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-lg-7 pushtop">
                              <h1><%# Eval("ProductName") %></h1>

                             <p>Description: </p>
                             <p><%# Eval("ProductDescription") %></p>
                             <p>Quantity: </p><asp:TextBox ID="txtPackageQuantity" TextMode="Number" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>                        
                             <asp:DropDownList  ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="DropDownList1_TextChanged"></asp:DropDownList> 

                             <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add to cart"  CommandName="AddToCart" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductID")%>'/>
                             </div>
                     </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: is this code defined inside the DropDownList1_TextChanged event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you

```
protected void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, ListViewSelectEventArgs e)
        {
            var lw = sender as ListView;
            var ddl = lw.Items[e.NewSelectedIndex].FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;
            var val = ddl.SelectedValue;
        }
```

Update:
There is no OnTextChanged="DropDownList1_TextChanged" on dropwdownlists (as explained in chat)
If u dont't attach to the listview event but to the dropwdonwlist event, you have to do it like this:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ddl = sender as DropDownList;
            var val = ddl.SelectedValue;
        }
```

Comment: This event won't fire when user selects something from the dropdown list which is in the template field of the list view, so this doesn't helps at all... I believe I need on selected index changing event from drop down list, but I can't seem to find it??? Thers only "on selected index changed"...

Comment: Thats the event ur looking for! then you have to add a DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged to the dropdownlist and then access the value there.

Comment: Can you write me the code how you think it should look like, because I'm not quite sure what to do with the code you gave me above... Thanks!

Comment: Okay sure, give me few minutes to get the code... Btw, this event should fire every time user changes the dropdown selection?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75589/discussion-between-perkes456-and-legends).

Comment: You should set AutoPostBack = "true" in the DropDownList if you want the SelectedIndexChanged to be fired when the user changes the selection

Comment: Paolo yes I figured it, and set that to true. Questions is now... is there a way that page doesnt refreshes every time user selects something from the dropdown list?

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is listview:

```
<asp:ListView ID="listProducts" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ProductID" OnItemDataBound="listProducts_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="listProducts_ItemCommand" OnSelectedIndexChanging="listProducts_SelectedIndexChanging">
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <div class="productoverlay">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 proizvod">
                         <div class="product">
                             <div class="glow"></div>
                             <img src='<%# "../productimg/" + Eval("FileName")%>'  alt='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>'/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-lg-1 price">
                         <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-lg-7 pushtop">
                          <h1><%# Eval("ProductName") %></h1>

                         <p>Description: </p>
                         <p><%# Eval("ProductDescription") %></p>
                         <p>Quantity: </p><asp:TextBox ID="txtPackageQuantity" TextMode="Number" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>                        
                         <asp:DropDownList  ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="DropDownList1_TextChanged"></asp:DropDownList> 

                         <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add to cart"  CommandName="AddToCart" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductID")%>'/>
                         </div>
                 </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

Is this what you needed?